# Loop for set of images

Tags: xcode, arrays, image, loops

Have an array of 18 pictures of golf holes listed in a table view. Once one is clicked it opens into a detailed view with a descriptive label. I added a tap gesture so that when the screen is tapped it advances to the next picture of the next hole instead of hitting the back button on the navigation controller. I want to make a loop to continue until I have reached all 18 holes. I currently have the tap gesture in the view did load method. Then once fired it calls another method that increases the index by one and displays the next picture and label. My question is do I continue the loop in the current method or is there a way to go back and call the view did load method again. Looking for the "proper logic" thanks.